# Color changing using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, colors

```
<div id="Button" ><a href="#">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="thumb" >Thumb</div>

-------------------------------

$('.thumb').addClass('new').css("background-color", "yellow");
callmeman();
$('#Button').click(function () {
    callmeman();
});

function callmeman(){
     if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new').css("background-color"," yellow")) {
         $('.thumb').css("background-color", "red");
     } else {
         $('.thumb').css("background-color", "yellow");
     }
 }
```

i want if i click the button then it checks if thumb is yellow then it changes it to red, and if i click it again it checks if its red then changes to yellow and so on..

and is there other ways to call the function i have done it like this : 
callmeman();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="thumb" class="yellowBackground">thumb</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.yellowBackground {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.redBackground {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JS** (using jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        changeThumb();
    });
});

function changeThumb() {
    $("#thumb").toggleClass("yellowBackground redBackground");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the [**hasClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function and [**css()**](https://api.jquery.com/css/) function. The hasClass function doesn't return a jQuery object. The if statement is looking for a `TRUE/FALSE` value.

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new').css("background-color", "yellow");
callmeman();
$('#Button').click(callmeman);

function callmeman(){
     if ($('.thumb').hasClass('new') && $('.thumb').css("background-color") == 'yellow') {
         $('.thumb').css("background-color", "red");
     } else {
         $('.thumb').css("background-color", "yellow");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to create 2 class i.e.

```
.yellowClass {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.redClass {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

*Script*

```
$('.thumb').addClass('new yellowClass');
function callmeman() {
    $('.thumb').toggleClass('yellowClass redClass');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

make two css classes :

```
.yellow{
 background-color : #FFFF00
}

.red{
 background-color : #FF0000
 }
```

Add class yellow initially

```
$('.thumb').addClass('yellow');
```

on click, just toggle classes like this

```
$('#Button').click(callmeman);
function callmeman(){
 $('.thumb').toggleClass('yellow red');
}
```